# BadKeyError: Invalid string key incorrect padding

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using a standard couple of lines of code to retrieve a key from a http get request and use it to get something from the datastore, but am running into a problem that I haven't encountered before.  This is only happening on the live (deployed) version - there are no problems when running the code on the dev server.

The code snippet:

```
  imgId = self.request.args.get("img_id")
  imageInfo = db.get(imgId)
```

And an error example:

```
    BadKeyError: Invalid string key  ahFjeWJlcm5hdXRzcHJvamVjdHINCxIFSW1hZ2UY1oYDDA=. Details: Incorrect padding
```

If I log the value of imgId right before the db.get, it is correct (without the appended "=" from the debug message).  Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried logging the result of comparing the input string with a test one? It's obviously not exactly the same, or you wouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: Ok so the actual value being passed to the get request in this case is getting a %20 whitespace added prefixed to it for some reason - this whitespace isnt showing up on either end of the get request though, so I'm really at a loss as to why it's cropping up...

Comment: I presume you're thinking out loud, since there's no way we can help without seeing the code in question, and more debugging details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing url encoding.
try:

```
imgId = urllib.unquote(self.request.args.get("img_id"))
```

maybe spaces?
try:

```
imgId = urllib.unquote(self.request.args.get("img_id")).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not URL encoding, then maybe it has something to do with the `args` variable.

If it's a HTTP GET request:

```
imgId = self.request.GET.get("img_id")
imageInfo = db.get(imgId)
```

If it's a HTTP POST request:

```
imgId = self.request.POST.get("img_id")
imageInfo = db.get(imgId)
```

Comment: I should've mentioned I'm using Tipfy, hence the args variable.